# "cross-product" of data frames

Tags: r

I was wondering if there was a way to take a "cross-product" of data frames with non-numeric entries.  I have a single-column data frame df.RICS with strings as entries (length 235), and another df.dates with dates as entries (length 3004). I want a data frame with each date matched up to each string in df.RICS:

```
    dates
1   2004-04-23
2   2004-04-24
3   2004-04-25
4   2004-04-26
5   2004-04-27
6   2004-04-28
7   2004-04-29
8   2004-04-30
9   2004-05-01
10  2004-05-02

    RICS
1   AA.N
2   AAP
3   AAP.N
4   AAPL.O
5   ABGL.L
```

Can I use expand.grid(df.RICS, df.dates) without converting to numeric values?

Right now all I have is:

```
> expand.grid(datesAsVec, RICSAsVec, stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
        Var1 Var2
1 2004-04-23 AA.N
Warning message:
In format.data.frame(x, digits = digits, na.encode = FALSE) :
  corrupt data frame: columns will be truncated or padded with NAs
```

Comment: What kind of "matched up" do you have in mind? I.e. what would have been the function to use with `outer`?

Comment: your vectors have NAs in them, which may be from however you made dataframes into vectors. if that's the case, just extract the columns in your call to expand.grid instead, or if the dataframes have NAs in them, wrap their references in na.omit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If your operation works with character data, you could convert the data.frames to character matrices, `outer` works on these.

   ```
   > df <- data.frame (a = LETTERS [1:3], b = 4:6, c = Sys.Date ())
   > df
     a b          c
   1 A 4 2012-06-01
   2 B 5 2012-06-01
   3 C 6 2012-06-01
   > sapply (df, as.character)
        a   b   c           
   [1,] "A" "4" "2012-06-01"
   [2,] "B" "5" "2012-06-01"
   [3,] "C" "6" "2012-06-01"
   > class (sapply (df, as.character))
   [1] "matrix"
   ```
2. If the function is vectorized, nstead of using `outer` you could also repeat the two matices appropriately and directly use the function.
3. If the function doesn't work on character, it's going to be more complicated... But you could have a look at `POSIXct`.

Comment: Think expand.grid can be used with the character matrices after playing with them a bit; thanks!

Answer (score 2):

you're looking for `expand.grid`

Comment: expand.grid works, but converts all the entries to numerics. Is there any way to end up with entries of the form.....

            Var1 Var2
    1 2004-04-23 AA.N


........so that I can keep the dates and strings as they are?

Comment: @user1428668 I think you should provide us with some exemplatory data...If we know what format you have, we are better able to help you! Have a look at `dput` as to how you can easily provide some of your data here.

Comment: sorry about that, here's an example of the data!